# Launch Eclipse Product File Programmatically?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to write an Eclipse plugin that lists all product files within a workspace and is able to launch them. Is there a way to launch an eclipse .product file programmatically?

On the file within the Eclipse ide there is a launch button. The file can be launched as well by right clicking and select: "Run as Eclipse Application."

Comment: This is a very broad area. Read everything in the [Program debug and launch support](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug.htm) help.

Comment: @greg-449 I don't see any reference to .product files in that help section. Are you saying that it is not possible to run .product files programmatically, and that is the alternative way to do something similar?

Comment: @mapeters It clearly must be possible since there is a 'Launch an Eclipse application' button of the .product file editor Overview page. But how this works is not covered by the documentation and may well use a lot of internal classes.

Answer (score 0):

look at -application flag to eclipse command line

see here : https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html

note you need to set the launcher that is platform specific too

Answer (score 0):

The code can be found inside org.eclipse.pde.ui.launcher.EclipseLaunchShortcut

I use the code this way:

```
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.iproduct.IProduct;
import org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.iproduct.IProductModel;
import org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.product.WorkspaceProductModel;
import org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.PDEPlugin;
import org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.launcher.LaunchAction;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class LaunchExecutor {

    private void launchProduct(IFile productFile) {
        String mode = "debug";
        IProductModel workspaceProductModel = new WorkspaceProductModel(productFile, false);
        try {
            workspaceProductModel.load();
        } catch (CoreException e) {
            PDEPlugin.log(e);
        }
        IProduct product = workspaceProductModel.getProduct();
        new LaunchAction(product, productFile.getFullPath().toOSString(), mode).run();
    }

}
```

Comment: Lots of internal classes there that you aren't supposed to use.